# Troubleshooting WINS errors

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, wins

We have domain controllers in three locations running the WINS role. Two of them are Windows 2008 and one is 2003. They are set up to replicate WINS with eachother every 30 minutes (the default, I believe).

Every hour each of them is logging Event ID 4102 errors:

> The connection was aborted by the
>   remote WINS. Remote WINS may not be
>   configured to replicate with the
>   server.

In addition, one of them is logging Event ID 4149 errors:

> Winsock Send could not send all the
>   bytes. The connection could have been
>   aborted by the remote client.

These errors are repeated every hour on each of the servers, but they occur at three different times throughout the hour.

Does anyone have any advice about how to troubleshoot this? The servers all have clean communication with eachother, and in spite of the errors WINS does seem to be replicating more or less correctly between them.

Comment: I know there's an ongoing religious debate about keeping or getting rid of WINS and I'm sure there are valid points to make about that, but for now we're really just trying to get to the bottom of what's causing these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you don't have any static mappings in one server that conflict with dynamic mappings in the others. The WINS server is notorious for throwing scary sounding errors while still working fine, behind the scenes.

I wouldn't get rid of WINS unless you know that you can get by w/o NetBIOS name resolution. I have no great love of NetBIOS name resolution, but most networks that I've tried to run "NetBIOS free" have had some kind of "gotcha" application or service that blindly attempts to do NetBIOS name resolution. It's demoralizing that we can't get rid of a crappy old protocol like NetBIOS, but that's the way it seems to be.

Comment: Yes there are a couple of static mappings and I'll follow up on them and make sure they aren't conflicting with valid DHCP addresses.  Would that really cause connection aborted messages, though?

Comment: WINS is a notoriously "Microsoft"-ey protocol / implementation, w/ memory buffers being written "raw" onto the wire w/o serialization, being read back, etc.  I found this article that led me in that direction, but, admittedly, it is a bit of a shot in the dark: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc975630.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to just get rid of WINS.  Seriously.  You don't need it at all unless you've got some genuinely ancient apps that use WINS for name resolution; otherwise you can just get rid of it.